# Facebook login with angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, facebook-login

I am working on project on angularjs, i have to implement Facebook login service there. I am new to angularjs. Can anybody suggest me any helpful tutorial(step by step) about the Facebook login service implementation.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try searching [ngmodules.org](http://ngmodules.org/) for some inspiration. There are a couple of modules for this, like [AngularJS-Facebook-Login](http://ngmodules.org/modules/AngularJS-Facebook-Login) or [ngFacebook](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngFacebook).

Also, [this](https://github.com/Ciul/angular-facebook) is a nice resource

Comment: thank you @Laura, I it was really helpful, specially the Sample application demo. I need to do the same thing for twitter. is it possible ?

Comment: one more thing.. how can we use session in angularjs to store data and read data?

Comment: haven't use twiter, but i suppose you could find some useful modules as well, maybe https://github.com/simtechmedia/angulartwitter. Also, there is a module including all main social networks: https://github.com/djds4rce/angular-socialshare

Comment: thanks @Laura ,but how can we use session in angularjs to store data and read data? –

Comment: you should create a different question for that, or search through the existent ones.