# Login facebook with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, facebook, ionic-framework

Well, I am doing a login my facebook application angular js + ionic. Everything is fine but I need to see the possibility that if there is a facebook application installed on the device to open the application and do not need to login. There is that possibility ?. I am using the library OpenFB of angularjs.

Comment: I don't know if you are still looking for an answer, but look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23730783/facebook-login-with-angularjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, even if the Facebook App is installed, you will have to authorize. Remember, you don´t authorize Facebook, but you authorize your specific App.

Comment: That is more than clear, maybe I did not express well. What I need is that if asked to authorize or not, but to open the Facebook app installed and not in the browser Jump to content Log again where it is necessary to allow it to check whether access permissions. I mean right?

Comment: It is possible, just not with OpenFB.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but not with OpenFB, you can use [phonegap-facebook-plugin](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin), it deals with native integration with the Facebook app if that's the case or use a webview just like OpenFB if the app is not installed.

Be aware that if you install it from Cordova Registry (using `cordova plugin add https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin.git --variable APP_ID="123456789" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication"`) you should fix `FacebookSDK.framework` symlink on Xcode for it to work on iOS.
Read more details on the [oficial documentation.](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/facebook/)

Comment: the question is about not requiring authorization if the facebook app is installed, but you ALWAYS need authorization. my answer is correct.